# SQL - How to select a row having a column with max value without using sub query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

```
      date         value
    18/5/2010        40
    18/5/2010        20
    20/5/2010        60
    18/5/2010        30
    17/5/2010        10
    16/5/2010        40
    18/5/2010        60
    18/5/2010        25
```

**Output**

```
date           value
18/5/2010        60
20/5/2010        60
```

I need to query for the row having max(value)(i.e. 60). So, here we get two rows.
the date can be in any order

**Plz do not use  SUBQUERY**

I need a dynamic query without using sub query

**NESTED QUERY** will be fine ...

I have tried that using rownum ... Where rownum< some_value  ...but it is not dynamic

Comment: have you tried using `MAX`? [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions085.htm) is a link that will help you get started if you're not familiar.

Comment: Is that a joke? I already did that .. Using sub query now i want it to be solved through single or nested query   read it carefully.... So max over partition by i hv done that  logic...

Comment: Also, do you make a habit of insulting people who are trying to help you? How does that work out generally?

Comment: First of all i got the solution and  i'm not insulting him, just telling him to read my q once again  ...

Comment: @apc I think the -4 score on his question answers yours...

Comment: Let's make that -5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 12c the FETCH clause allows you to do this

```
select * from the_table
 order by value desc
 FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES;
```

Comment: This is only valid in Oracle 12.

Comment: Well i'm not using 12c ... But thank you at least you replied  ☺ your logic is strong ... And the reason i dont want nested query because i'm fetching more than 80000 rows +8 columns  so already there  are  outer queries and i have already done that using a sub query so it not an efficient way and taking to much time to execute ....

Comment: @mayank all of that would have been good to put in your question instead of a comment on an answer.

Comment: @SandPiper okay  :)